# Javascript conditional time range format function

Tags: javascript, function, time-format

I am using React for my frontend app.

I have two different time format of data.

One is like this `08-10` and another one is like this `05:00-05:30`.

Most of the time format data is like this `08-10`, few are like `05:00-05:30`.

After getting the time date data, I used `map` function and pass to my `time-format` helper function, In my browser I want to display my data like this `05:00-05:30`.

My helper  function do like this: if the time looks like this `08-10` then the function will split it into two then add `:` and convert them into `08:00-10:00`. As I mentioned I have two different time format data, when the data come like this `05:00-05:30` then my helper function convert them like  `0500-0530`.

I want to render my function conditionally if the data is like `05:00-05:30` then return as it is, if the data is like this `08-10` then convert them into `08:00-10:00`. I don't know how to do that in my helper function.

```js
const toTimeRangeFormat = (range) => {
  console.log(range);

  const [start, end] = range?.split("-");
  const toFourDigitTime = (time) => {
    const [hours, minutes] = time.split(":");
    return hours.padStart(2, "0") + (minutes ? minutes : ":00");
  };

  if (start && end) {
    return toFourDigitTime(start) + " - " + toFourDigitTime(end);
  }

  return range;
};

const time = ["08-10", "05:00-05:30"];

time.filter((i) => {
  if (typeof i === "string") {
    return toTimeRangeFormat(i);
  }
});

console.log(toTimeRangeFormat());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seemed to work if you call it correctly

I assume you want this though

```js
const re = /(\d{2}):?(\d{2})?/; // take the (set of) two digits from NN:NN, NNNN or NN - the ? means optional
const toFourDigitTime = time => {
  const [hours, minutes] = time.match(re).slice(1); // ignore result[0]
  return `${hours.padStart(2, "0")}:${minutes ? minutes : "00"}`;
};

const toTimeRangeFormat = (range) => {
  const [start, end] = range ?.split("-");
  if (start && end) {
    return toFourDigitTime(start) + " - " + toFourDigitTime(end);
  }

  return range;
};

const time = ["08-10", "05:00-05:30"];

const time1 = time.map(str => toTimeRangeFormat(str));

console.log(time1);
```

Comment: Thanks. Running the code was not the issue. I think I did not explain well.
I share my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-star-fx70e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Did you get what I mean.

Comment: What does the regex do?